# How to bind PreferenceFragment to back end?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencefragment

Is it possible to send requests when user changes settings on PreferenceFragment? I don't need SharedPreferences feature, I just need to sync PreferenceFragment with back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it has method for  registering listener: registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(),
you can do it via implementing SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener interface and registering prefs for changes listening, something like:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    // here you can implement back end pushes
    // http://square.github.io/retrofit/ is a good choice
}

Comment: So is it true that anyways I will have saving data on disk's space? So maybe better to implement own preferences from scratch.

Comment: SharedPreferences is just convenient and easy approach for doing that, but you can use any other method you like (sqlite, file, network ...)